Selenium Server throws java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument on startUp
I am new to Selenium-Grid and i am trying to build a small local Selenium Grid Hub-Node project.
But up on trying to start the server I am running into zmq.ZError$IOException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument.
To start the server I am using
java -jar selenium-server-4.24.0.jar hub
I am using java 22.0.1 on a macOS 14.7.
The full console log is:
15:32:28.569 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
15:32:28.572 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
15:32:29.499 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:4443]
15:32:29.537 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:4442 and tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:4443
15:32:29.546 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
zmq.ZError$IOException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at zmq.io.net.tcp.TcpUtils.setOption(TcpUtils.java:119)
    at zmq.io.net.tcp.TcpUtils.setReuseAddress(TcpUtils.java:104)
    at zmq.io.net.tcp.TcpListener.accept(TcpListener.java:266)
    at zmq.io.net.tcp.TcpListener.acceptEvent(TcpListener.java:82)
    at zmq.io.IOObject.acceptEvent(IOObject.java:106)
    at zmq.poll.Poller.run(Poller.java:266)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Net.java:447)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Net.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(SocketChannelImpl.java:289)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(SocketChannelImpl.java:73)
    at zmq.io.net.tcp.TcpUtils.setOption(TcpUtils.java:112)
    ... 6 more


i also tried running it with -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true because I read it might has something to do with IPv4 vs IPv6 but the error stays the same.
I also tried multiple selenium-server-versions.
If I try to run it as standalone with java -jar selenium-server-4.24.0.jar standalone no errors appear.
Any Ideas?
